# When I scrolled the tableView cell, the running timer in this cell will reset and stop running

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer, countdown

There is a timer and start button in every cell, when I click the start button in that cell, the timeLabel will start to show the countdown.

Now everything works well but I found that when I scroll the running timer out of the screen and scroll it back, the timer will reset and stop.

cellForRow:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! TimerTableViewCell

    cell.timer?.invalidate()
    let item = myTimerList[indexPath.row]
    cell.timerName.text = item.timerName
    cell.secondLeftLabel.text = "\(item.timerSecond)"      
    return cell
}
```

I want the timer to still be running when I scroll the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Hi when you dequeueReusableCell the cell will be reused which will make the cell to get refreshed due to which you are getting the timer again from start if less cell you may remove **dequeueReusableCell** or **you can keep an array to store the timer count of every cell.**

**Assign array val when cell declaring and update in array every cell 
 timer increments.**

Comment: yes, I agree with you and I think the problem is caused by the dequeueReusableCell. But could you be more specific? because I have no idea where I should place the array you mentioned. here is my original code : https://app.box.com/s/axluqkjg0f7zjyigdmx1lau0c9m3ka47

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that may be helpful.

UITableViewCells only exist while on the screen. So what you are experiencing is the expected behavior. 
Basically you will need the timers to exists outside the scope of the UITableViewCell otherwise they will be destroyed when they go off the screen. So here is how you could accomplish this:

Create a subclass of UITableVIew as such (you should use this class instead of the TableViewController you are currently using, or simply add the code that comes later to your current TableViewController class):

```
class HeXiaoManTableViewController:  UITableViewController {

}
```

In this subclass, create an array (or data structure of your choice) to store the timers. I assume you are using NSTimer but this will work for whatever timer class you have.

```
class HeXiaoManTableViewController:  UITableViewController {

    public var timerArray: [NSTimer] = []
}
```

Now when you create the cells, add a new timer to the array. For the array, I'm storing a UITableViewCell in the array according to it's index. So the first UITableViewCell (index 0) will go in the index 0 of array... But say the user scrolls up and down, showing that first cell multiple times. I'm assuming you want that timer to only start once. So you need to check if the timer already exists. If it does, then leave it alone. Otherwise add the timer. You can customize this to the functionality you desire :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var timer = NSTimer()
    timer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: update, userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    if (timerArray.indices.contains(index)) {
        timerArray.insert(timer, at: index)
    }
}
```

You should be able to access this array at a later point to get individual timers. Hope this helped!

**Edit: changes to make in your classes**

**TimerTableViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TimerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

public var timeInLabel: Int = -1
public var viewController: ViewController?
var index: Int = -1
var timer:Timer?

var tableView: UITableView? {
    var view = self.superview
    while (view != nil && view!.isKind(of: UITableView.self) == false) {
        view = view!.superview
    }
    return view as? UITableView
}

@IBOutlet weak var timerName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secondLeftLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    timer?.invalidate()

}

@IBAction func playButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    RunLoop.current.add(self.timer!, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)

}

@objc func updateTimer() {

    var timeInLabel = Int(secondLeftLabel.text!)!
    timeInLabel -= 1
    viewController?.timerArray[index] = timeInLabel
    secondLeftLabel.text = String(timeInLabel)

}

}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

public var timerArray: [Int] = []

var myTimerList = CustomTimerList()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    for timer in CustomTimerList.timerList {
        timerArray.append(timer.timerSecond)
    }
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return CustomTimerList.timerList.count
}

var selectedIndexArray:[Int] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! TimerTableViewCell
    cell.timer?.invalidate()
    let item = CustomTimerList.timerList[indexPath.row]
    cell.timerName.text = item.timerName
    cell.secondLeftLabel.text = "\(timerArray[indexPath.row])"
    cell.index = indexPath.row
    cell.viewController = self

    return cell


}

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I try to integrate your code with mine, but I found it doesn't work, this is my original code: https://app.box.com/s/axluqkjg0f7zjyigdmx1lau0c9m3ka47

Comment: Please post code. Any more information could be helpful

Comment: here is the code I shared in box:https://app.box.com/s/axluqkjg0f7zjyigdmx1lau0c9m3ka47

Comment: just a few minutes I'll take a look

Comment: I will mark your answer as the recommended answer if I solve the problems that I should click the button to let it run again :)  in case someone use this way but has the same timer-stop problem. Thank you again!